# Splitting string using operator in android for calculator App

Tags: android, string, split, operand

I want to make a calculator App.  For this I need to be able to split a string into two when there is an operand between them.  I tried my code like this:

String[] operation= display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));
 currentOperator contain my operator i.e + - /  or *

I tried entering 12 + 12

When I displayed my operation[0] and operation[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RaJa.png) result shown is 1 and +1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RaJa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a format such as **operator:value:value** eg. +:12:12
In this case you could use:

```
String[]example=yourString.split(":");
if(example.length==3){
String operator=example[0];
int value1=Integer.parseInt(example[1]);
int value2=Integer.parseInt(example[2]);
}
```